# Printing out contents

Tags: spweb

how can I print out $user["EMail"] from below code snippet

```
cls  
$web =Get-SPWeb http://wer.com/sites/wooly/
$list=$web.Lists["User Information List"]
$user =$list.GetItemById(##)
$user["EMail"].print()?????????????????????
```

I tried $user["EMail"].print() , I tried $user["EMail"].echo() but no luck. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something along the lines of this:

```
Write-output ($user["Email"])
```

Comment: Or just $user["Email"] on a single line

Comment: That works too though I usually like to be more explicit over output using `write-output`, `write-host` or `write-verbose` in order to direct the output to the proper channel

Comment: Very true! And also more readable. But for e.g using powershell as debugging tool it is nice to know the shortcut :)